# Why is this structure in typescript class resulting in a runtime error when it compiles just fine?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor, automated-tests

I am writing for Protractor with Jasmine. I am well-versed in Java and browser-testing, but am new to JavaScript and Protractor.

I am working on moving my code over to the "new" style of using async and awaits to move ahead of the control flow changes (if I'm mistaken in my understanding of that, I apologize) and I'm running into issues when it comes to converting my page object classes over.  At first I tried to type my function at "Line A" as Promise, but I got the error that "type any[] is not convertible to type ElementArrayFinder".  On suggestion I changed it to what is currently there "Promise" which compiles, but fails to run with the error below the given code. Before my conversion I was simply passing the ElementArrayFinder object around no problem and my code worked, so I have previously working code, I just need to figure out how to make it work in this new structure.

```
// my po class
...
// Breadcrumb methods
async getBreadCrumbs(): Promise<any> {  // Line A
   return await element.all(by.css('bread-crumbs span'));
}

async getProjectNameBreadCrumbText() {
    const breadCrumbs: ElementArrayFinder = await this.getBreadCrumbs();
    return await breadCrumbs.get(2).getText();
}

async getProjectMapperBreadCrumbText() {
    const breadCrumbs: ElementArrayFinder = await this.getBreadCrumbs();
    return await breadCrumbs.get(3).getText();
}
```

Appears to compile fine without IDE errors in Webstorm, but when I run it I get the error:

```
Failed: breadCrumbs.get is not a function
TypeError: breadCrumbs.get is not a function
```

And in case it matters here's code using the above PO class that is causing the failure when it calls the code at run-time:

```
it('test case', async function() {
...
await expect(mapperPage.getProjectMapperBreadCrumbText()).toEqual(mapperPage.MAPPER_BREADCRUMB);
...
});
```

I'm open to constructive criticism on how I should be writing this code, I'm mostly winging it from piecing together code bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you returning **element.all(by.css('bread-crumbs span'))** from **getBreadCrumbs()** your other functions are actually receiving an array of  *WebElement* instead of an *ElementArrayFinder*. So you should be able to call

> breadcrumbs[n].getText()

In your functions

My personal suggestion would be for you to move away from a function returning your selector and instead set them as properties of your page object class:

> public breadcrumbs = element.all(by.css('bread-crumbs span'));

Which simplifies **getProjectNameBreadCrumbText()** to:

`async getProjectNameBreadCrumbText(): Promise<string> {
    return this.breadCrumbs.get(2).getText();
}`

And your test to:

`it('test case', async function() {
...
expect(await mapperPage.getProjectMapperBreadCrumbText())
    .toEqual(mapperPage.MAPPER_BREADCRUMB);
...
});`

If you'd like I would be happy to give you my general format for page objects, spec, and config I've been using for async/await with the Promise Manager disabled.

Comment: This was 100% it and your explanation made complete sense.  Thanks for being concise and to the point! If you reach out to my email I would love to see how you structure your work.

Answer (score 0):

Because `element.all(by.css('bread-crumbs span'));` seems to result in `undefined`.
Undefined matches any type in Typescript unless you turn it off in your tsconfig. Also Typescript transtiples to JavaScript and it does not enforce type correctness at runtime. So especially if you are using 3rd party scripts, don't rely on the type declarations without checking them.